# Tag wiki: Links to questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

At the moment, only a few tags has wiki entries, I'm about to give some basic descriptions to the tags.

Question: Should one add links to "typical" questions related to the tag? Or is this already clear since one can click on the tag icon to get the questions with the best score?

Comment: I would not link to such questions. The linked to "typical" questions would get a lot of visibility over the rest, which is not really desirable or fair, and also would make them not "typical".